# Comma separated

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

I want a comma separated list for the var $stuff:

```
<?php foreach($stuffs as $stuff): ?>
<?=$stuff?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The array looks like this:

```
[letters] => Array
  (
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 1
    [three] => 1
  )
```

I tried implode but that is not working... and I don't understand why?
So must be overlooking something super simple.

```
<?php echo implode(", ", $stuff) ?>
```

doesn't do a thing but,

```
<?php echo implode(", ", $stuffs) ?>
```

echo's

one, two, three, one, two, three, one, two, three

3 times. Once for every key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop if you're imploding. The implode function will  do that for you. So:

```
<?php echo implode(", ", $stuffs) ?>
```

By itself, without the foreach loop, should do the trick.

Comment: im stupid... iv'e been looking at this for half an hour... and totally ignored the foreach. Went back to delete this post but there you are. =)